# How to store amount of objects in Spring data

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

**Description**

I have a system where I can add `Component` and save it to DB(Mysql). After that a can create `Product` which contains `Components` in different amount. 
As I understand table should be like `component_id|product_id|amount_of_component`

Component class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "component")
public class Component {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Product class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

  //something should be here
    private Component component;

}
```

**Question**

Which annotation or Collection I should use to create such relations between that entities ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use OneToMany with either Set or List. Here is an example:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn("product_id")
private Set<Component> component;
```

Please read the Hibernate documentation about Collection mapping: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections